# How to overlay a video on another video and also fade in a PNG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking to overlay a video on top of another video and then also add a fade in and fade out PNG.

I have the current command which works perfectly in merging two video files one on top of the other.

```
ffmpeg -y -i output.mp4 -i transparent.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=.7[u];[b][u]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]" -map [v] awsome.mp4
```

I need to now add a PNG on it as well that fades in at `1s` and fades out at `9.5s`.

Appreciate any and all advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -i output.mp4 -i transparent.mp4 -loop 1 -t 10 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=.7[u];[b][u]overlay=eof_action=pass[v];[2]fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=8.5:d=1:alpha=1[i];[v][i]overlay[v]" -map [v] awsome.mp4`

---

If the PNG needs to be scaled to video size, use scale2ref for the image as well.

`ffmpeg -y -i output.mp4 -i transparent.mp4 -loop 1 -t 10 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=.7[u];[b][u]overlay=eof_action=pass[v];[2][v]scale2ref[i][v];[i]fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=8.5:d=1:alpha=1[i];[v][i]overlay[v]" -map [v] awsome.mp4`

Comment: That is fantastic thank you Gyan, really appreciate your help, if by some chance you could tell me how to make the png scale as well that would be super.